# How can I add an attribute to unmatched attribute programatically?

Tags: php, magento, attributes

I am trying to create an attribute in magento programatically.But it always add this attribute to all attribute set. I want to add this attribute to unmatched attribute and then i want to add this attribute to specific attribute set.Here is my function :

```
public function createAttribute($attributeName, $adminLabel, $dataAttr = null, $type = "varchar") {
        $model = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_setup', 'core_setup');
        if ($dataAttr) {
            $data = $dataAttr;
        } else {
            $data = array(
                'type' => $type,
                'input' => 'text',
                'label' => $adminLabel,
                'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
               // 'attribute_set'=> '',
                'is_required' => '0',
                'is_comparable' => '1',
                'is_searchable' => '0',
                'is_unique' => '1',
                'is_configurable' => '1'
            );
        }
        $model->addAttribute('catalog_product', $attributeName, $data);
    }
```